# How to handle concurrent update to same table

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, rabbitmq

I have ASP.NET Web API application where client can perform update. When multiple concurrent requests reach the app server, they are divided by a load balancer.

I have two app servers and in front of them the load balancer, so the load is distributed. But at the backend, we have on premise SQL Server which is not scalable. So if API gets multiple requests at the same time, then update for a few requests failed because of a SQL Server timeout.

When I checked the stored procedure which is timing out, it is generating dynamic queries based on parameters sent and some configured tables.

Also I faced this issue when I tried to update table using simple update statement at pick times. Here table is updated by several applications at a time.

I am not sure what will be best strategy to resolve issue.

Shall I use RabbitMQ to minimize database load. But RabbitMQ might delay update since one of my business flow required real time update then performed some action.

Can somebody guide me to handle such scenarios?

Answer (score 1):

Most important consideration when serving multiple users performing updates: always use TRANSACTION for updating your database. Make sure that the transaction includes all SQL you need to update every table you need, it will be executed in one single go when you issue COMMIT.

Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/begin-transaction-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: will TRANSACTION locks entire table?

Comment: Between opening a TRANSACTION and its COMMIT the database will only make sure that when some exception occurs, the changes in the database will be undone during ROLLBACK. I now understand your question refers to concurrency, or concurrent access to tables. SQL Server has several options for that, I don't know which ones are default, or best strategy in your case. You may want to use application wide locks, or locking for tables.. refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/2014-toc/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide?view=sql-server-2014